# Django rest framework authentication

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I would like create authentication in Django. I'm trying to do everything according to [this](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication).
Unfortunately, at this moment I have two problems. Firstly, when I try to add `from rest_framework.authtoken import views` I have conflict with `from companies import views`. I need views from authtoken to `url(r'^api-token-auth/', views.obtain_auth_token)`. Secondly, when I use `/api-token-auth/` My problem is that I can log in only superuser, for other users in my database I get response - `"Unable to log in with provided credentials."`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'corsheaders',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'companies.apps.CompaniesConfig',
    'rest_framework.authtoken'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'pri.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'pri.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'pri',
        'USER': 'root',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    }
}

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    )
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use as to remove the conflicts.

```
from companies import views as companies_views
from rest_framework.authtoken import views as rest_auth_views
```

and use this in urls `url(r'^api-token-auth/', rest_auth_views.obtain_auth_token)`

Provide details is not enough to debug what cause authentication. Can you provide more code about your token based authentication.

Update:

After communicating with OP. He created the user using `UserSerializer` and that saving the password as plain text. And authentication not works.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 

    class Meta: 
        model = User 

        fields = '__all__'`

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        return user
```

Comment: I have added only `url(r'^api-token-auth/', views.obtain_auth_token)` to URL. I thought that it's enough because it's build-in. Do I have to add something for instance to my views?

Comment: @Wahtdbogh Yes. Can you include your settings about Django restframwork ?

Comment: Okay. Now what is your question? I see you have included basic and session authentication. Is it worked ?

Comment: My problem is that I can login only superuser, for other users in my database I get response - "Unable to log in with provided credentials."

Comment: Okay did you tried adding `ToekenAuthentication` classes in settings.py file.

Comment: Yes I have added and still the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145623/discussion-between-raja-simon-and-wahtdbogh).

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `TokenAuthentication` to your `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` in your `settings.py`.

From the docs,

> To use the TokenAuthentication scheme you'll need to configure the authentication classes to include TokenAuthentication.

So change your settings.py like this,

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    )
}
```

Comment: I have added and still the same problem.

Comment: How are you creating the users?? through admin site??

Comment: I have solved my problem. I supposed that the problem was not encrypted password in database and @RajaSimon helped me to change it in serializer.